# Design Suggestion - Class with Properties, Interface ( or abstract ) - Access issues

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a three classes namely "Class1", "Class2" and "Class3" and one interface IBase.

```
interface IBase
{
  + PrpCommon {get;set;}
}

Class1:IBase
{
 + PrpCommon {get;set;}

+ Class1Prp {get;set;} ( and few other properties )
}

Class2:IBase
{
 + PrpCommon {get;set;}
 + Class2Prp {get;set;} ( and few other properties )
}

Class3:IBase
{
  + PrpCommon {get;set;}
  + Class3Prp {get;set;} }

AccessClass
{

  AccessFunction(IBase)
{

    return IBase.PrpCommon;     
// here i need to access the other properties like Class3Prpr or Class2Prp or Class1Prp.
}
}

MainClass
{
  AccessClass.AccessFunction(new Class1)  
 // Here need to access the other properties like Class3Prpr or Class2Prp or Class1Prp.
 }
```

Is it possible??? I heard that through some constructor and can access it., but not through the Interface... Any idea.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I got this correctly. Do you want to access the properties of the derived classes inside AccessClass ?
In that case, one option would be to have a base class or an interface for AccessClass, specific implementations for each one of the IBase classes and an AccessClassFactory. Something like this:

```
interface IAccessClass
{
  AccessFunction<T>(T item) where T : IBase;
}

class AccessClass1 : IAccessClass<Class1>{
   AccessFunction(Class1 item){
      // here you can do whatever you want with the properties
   }
}

class AccessClassFactory{
   IAccessClass<T> Create<T>() where T : IBase{
      var classType = typeof(T);
      if(classType == typeof(Class1)) return new AccessClass1();
      // and so on
   }
}
```

I hope you got the idea!